# InvalidCursorName, ProgrammingError, OperationalError related to postgres cursor while changing model

Tags: django, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

When we moved from aws to local provided we started to observe these three errors. It appears randomly while changing model.

```
InvalidCursorName 
/core/family/{object_id}/change/
cursor "_django_curs_140667503112576_sync_1371" does not exist
```

```
ProgrammingError 
/core/family/{object_id}/change/
cursor "_django_curs_140667503112576_sync_1139" already exists
```

```
OperationalError
/core/family/{object_id}/change/
cursor "_django_curs_140667503112576_sync_4004" does not exist
```

This problem doesn't appear on our staging server, I can't neither reproduce it locally. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you applied all your migrations - `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes, was resolved by changing provider's pooling option to session state. It was all about pg_bouncer